# React fetching and updating view from database array

Tags: arrays, sorting, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to load my initial data from a Firebase database. Currently, I can update the state with the contents of one entry in my database. I would however like to have more control of what is rendered through an array, but how can I bind cases to an array and iterate over these in react, but only after executing componentDidMount()?

This is the error I am receiving:

```
firebase.js:283 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {home}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Cases`.
```

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

class Cases extends Component{

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = ({
      cases: 10
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {

      const rootRef = firebase.database().ref('cases');
      const casesRef = rootRef.child('home');
      rootRef.on('value', snap => {
        this.setState({
          cases: snap.val()

        })
      })
    }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
          <h2>Cases</h2>
          {this.state.cases}
      </div>)
  }
}

export default Cases;
```

Comment: Can you send what is the content of your this.state.cases?

Comment: Hi Sergey, thanks you for taking the time! I debugged a bunch and found some more information. However I opened a new question to present the problem more clearly. If you want to have a look I uploaded all of the information to this thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39114285/rendering-javascript-object-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

basically the data which is come from firebase is in the object form you cant directly print the object as a child in react you have to loop on your object then push in the array and then you can print array value on the react child